# ¿Cómo abrir 2 aplicaciones al mismo tiempo desde Python?

Tags: python, windows, batch, proceso

Tengo una aplicación en Python 2.7 y mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un botón ligado a un evento, el cual si lo presiono me tiene que abrir 2 aplicaciones al mismo tiempo mediante un 'batch', las cuales son: teclado en pantalla de windows y un software que instalé llamado Harmonny XB5Soft.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
def abrir_programas():
   import os
   os.system(r'run_apps.cmd')
```

Dentro de ese batch tengo lo siguiente:

```
cd\
cd Program Files (x86)/Schneider Electric/HarmonyXB5SSoft/bin/
HarmonyXB5SSoft.exe
osk
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero al ejecutar ese batch no me abre los 2 programas al mismo tiempo. Lo que pasa es que la PC esta esperando a que se cierre el primer programa para abrir el teclado en pantalla, y lo que se busca, es que al presionar el botón y ejecutar la función abrir los 2 programas al mismo tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varias posibilidades:

- Usar [`start`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc770297(v=ws.11)):

  ```
  cd\
  cd Program Files (x86)/Schneider Electric/HarmonyXB5SSoft/bin/
  start /b HarmonyXB5SSoft.exe
  start /b osk
  ```
- Pasar del batch y lanzar ambos procesos desde Python vía [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) (`os.system` se considera obsoleto en la practica frente `subprocess`)

  ```
  import subprocess


  def abrir_programas():
      subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/Schneider Electric/HarmonyXB5SSoft/bin/HarmonyXB5SSoft.exe"])
      subprocess.Popen(["C:/WINDOWS/system32/osk.exe"])
  ```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, estaba rabado con os,system y subprocess me resolvio el problema